# Can a JS Path be customized to execute a click on a element (checkbox) SELENIUM, Java

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium

I am trying to make an automation test script in Selenium using Java. I have problems with checkboxes on the page because they are created using GWT I think and they have dynamic id-s, and every other tag or class is the same for all of them.

I have somehow managed to execute a click on the first one using javascriptExecutor and using the JS Path of the 'label' tag that I got right clicking on the element/copy/copy JS Path.
The path I got is: `document.querySelector("#ttip > div:nth-child(1) > span > label").click()`

Now the issue is that all of the checkboxes have the same JS Path and I am wondering if there is a way to change the JS Path to somehow affect only the checkbox that I want? Maybe something like adding indexes to the span and label elements?? -> `document.querySelector("#ttip > div:nth-child(1) > span(1) > label(1)").click()`

1. This is one of the checkboxes that I managed to execute a click over JavascriptExecutor with this code

```
public void clickChckBoxPretezita() {
        js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"#ttip > div:nth-child(1) > span > label\").click()");
    }
```

```
<span class="v-checkbox v-widget">
     <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-46" tabindex="0">
     <label for="gwt-uid-46" style=""></label>
</span>
```

1. This is the second one and I can't manage to execute a click on it.

```
<span class="v-checkbox v-widget">
     <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-uid-47" tabindex="0">
     <label for="gwt-uid-47" style=""></label>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute using indexes you can follow below approach.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
js.executeScript("document.querySelector(\"#ttip > div:nth-child(arguments[0]) > span:nth-child(arguments[1]) > label:nth-child(arguments[2])\").click()", divIndex,spanIndex,labelIndex);
```